# How to export text annotations with links using plotly python?

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-python

I am using python plotly '5.1.0' for a bubble plot.
What I would like to do is to also add some text annotations containing links to web pages. All works fine when I show the figure in jupyter notebook, however I haven't managed to save the plot with working links as a picture (my favorite format would be pdf but I tried basically all the available ones).

Is this possible with plotly? Are there alternatives to achieve that with other libraries?

**Edit:** the final goal is to insert the picture in a pdf using latex, so solution directly compatible with this usage are preferred :)

Here same toy code to reproduce the behavior:

```
import plotly.express as px
df = px.data.gapminder()

fig = px.scatter(df.query("year==2007"), x="gdpPercap", y="lifeExp",
                 size="pop", color="continent",
                 hover_name="country", log_x=True, size_max=60)
fig.add_annotation(text="""here is my <a href="https://rdcu.be/cB1Ds"><b>paper</b></a>""", x=4, y=50)
fig.show()
```

The result correctly displays a clickable link:
[image: notebook preview: the link works]

However, when I save it the link disappears:

```
fig.write_image("fig1.pdf", engine="kaleido") # I also tried "orca" but doesn't help
```

[image]

Comment: Try this :`fig.write_html('./data/file_text.html')` If you save the link in html format, the format is still valid.

Comment: Thanks @r-beginners, I forgot to mention that I want to include the saved picture in a pdf document. To the best of my knowledge, it is not possible to insert an HTML figure directly into latex. I think a possible workaround may be [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/560318/258324), but I still have to try it. So I leave the question open for the moment to see if there's a direct solution, thanks :)

Comment: Have you checked [this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63087172/how-to-export-plotly-graphs-along-with-other-html-content-into-pdf)?

Comment: Thanks @KateOrlova, no I hadn't seen it. If I understood correctly, this suggests saving the plot as an HTML file and then using WeasyPrint to render it as pdf, is that correct? Anyway, the actual steps how to do the conversion are quite obscure in that question and the answer is not checked as solution. Could you guide me a bit more through this?

Answer (score 1):

**Short answer**

Though not elegant, I would suggest to create an image without a link and then use `tikz` and `hyperref` to add the link to the image manually in latex:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{scope}
    \node[anchor=south west,inner sep=0] (image) at (0,0){\includegraphics[width=0.7\textwidth]{scatter_without_link.png}};
\begin{scope}[x={(image.south east)},y={(image.north west)}]
    \node [anchor=west] (note) at (0.6,0.70) {\href{https://stackoverflow.com}{Link}};
\end{scope}
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

**Long answer**

You could create an svg with clickable links. A minimum working example using `matplotlib` is

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.scatter([1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6])
text = ax.annotate("Link", xy=(2,5), xytext=(2.2,5.5),
                url='https://stackoverflow.com', 
                bbox=dict(color='w', alpha=1e-6, url='https://stackoverflow.com'))
fig.savefig('scatter.svg')
```

Then convert the svg to pdf, e.g. using [inkscape](https://inkscape.org/) and the command line:

```
inkscape -D --export-type="pdf" scatter.svg --export-latex
```

This results in a pdf with the scatter plot and a clickable hyperlink.

*However:* Preserving the hyperlink when embedding the pdf in your latex file (e.g. using the [svg package](https://ctan.org/pkg/svg) or simply `\input{scatter.pdf_tex}`) is a more difficult problem as pdftex seems to drop the annotations from the included file (see this 10-year-old question [How to preserve hyperlinks in included PDF?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14620/how-to-preserve-hyperlinks-in-included-pdf)).

*Note:* If you want to use the svg package, make sure that (1) Inkscape is installed and on the system path and (2) latex runs with shell-escape (`--shell-escape`) enabled.

*Note 2*: For displaying the matplotlib example in jupyter notebook:

```
%config InlineBackend.figure_formats = ['svg']
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.scatter([1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6])
text = ax.annotate("Link", ... )  # same as above
plt.plot()
```

Comment: Sorry for the matplotlib example (not an plotly expert). Also: Happy to hear if anyone finds a solution for including the svg/pdf while preserving the hyperlinks!

Comment: Thanks a lot! I tried the long answer but it doesn't seem to work for me as I can't see a clickable link neither in the plt preview nor in the saved file...do I need some particular matplotlib setup or additional packages?

Comment: The short solution could do the trick instead! is a bit hard to manage since I have 10 annotations and I would need i) text on multiple lines and ii) font size/style is consistent with the rest of the plot...I found some possible strategies ([1](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/24372/how-to-add-newline-within-node-using-tikz), [2](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/107057/adjusting-font-size-with-tikz-picture)) but still need to make them work properly...I leave it open for the moment to see if something else comes up :)

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. Hyperlinks are standard matplotlib functionality, so no additional packages required ([link](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/misc/hyperlinks_sgskip.html)). Hard to tell why the example does not work for you. I tried again and for me, opening the file `scatter.svg` in the browser as well as displaying the plot in jupyter notebook results in a scatter plot with a clickable link (named 'Link' in the example). I'll add the jupyter notebook code in the answer (though there are also other ways to preview svg files).

Comment: Indeed it seems weird... I just copied your code in a notebook. In case it may be relevant I am using Python 3.9.6 and matplotlib '3.4.2'

Comment: strange... nothing special in the code... both annotations and hyperlinks are available for earlier matplotlib versions (I used python 3.8.8 and matplotlib 3.4.3)

Comment: Sorry I didn't realize you edited the answer, anyway I can confirm that matplotlib is now working if I add `%config InlineBackend.figure_formats = ['svg']` (both in the notebook and if I open the SVG file with chrome as suggested by @Bilal Qandeel )  :)
Unfortunately I still have problems when converting from svg to pdf ( I am afraid I might have some problems with my inkscape installation :/ ): it says `Invalid option --export-type=pdf`, any idea what that means?

Comment: Which Inkscape version do you use? If not already using it you should consider upgrading to a 1.+ version. There were some major changes regarding the command line parameters... Alternatively you could use the Inkscape gui: Open a new document and open the .svg with `file > open`. Then use `file > save as` and choose `pdf` format to save the image as pdf. That should work (tested with Inkscape v1.1).

Comment: I must have done some mess with the inkscape installation, however I think it is now working. Nonetheless the pdf inclusion fails in the original pdf, as you mentioned :/

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the available solutions are not always trusted. That, perhaps, explains why there is no standard one. I was about to suggest [@rosa b.](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5039333/rosa-b)'s exact solution, it just did not work for me when I tried to replicate it at my end. Maybe because I used a challenging `svg` sample that contained two different types of hyperlinks: one around a shape and another around a text to cover all possibilities as follows:

**links.svg**

```
<svg viewBox="0 0 100 100" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"> 
 <!-- A link around a shape -->
 <a href="http://www.example.com">
   <circle cx="50" cy="40" r="35" stroke="green" fill="red"/>
     <text x="50" y="40" text-anchor="middle" font-size="0.5em">
       www.example.com
     </text>
 </a>

 <!-- A link around a text -->
 <a href="http://www.foo.bar">
   <text x="50" y="90" text-anchor="middle">
     Foo.Bar
   </text>
 </a>
</svg>
```

When I carried out `rosa b.`'s solution, using the following command under a `Windows` environment:

```
inkscape.com --export-area-drawing --export-type="pdf" --export-filename=links.pdf --export-latex links.svg
```

It indeed generated a `links.tex_pdf` file that, also, did not contain the link to the text hyperlink correctly suggesting adding it manually using `\href{}`.

I tried another solution by printing the `svg` to a `pdf` using Google Chrome since many PDF transformers filter off those hyperlinks as unwanted annotations. The print has to happen without headers or footers and at a 0 margin. This kept the `csv`'s hyperlinks intact. Now coming to the second challenge to include this good `pdf` into `LaTeX` since, again, LaTeX inclusion of `pdf` do filter off the annotations, again!

I learned about a package called [`pax`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/pax) that you can include to better add the `pdf`s with links. I followed their recommendation and ended up with the following:

**links.tex**

```tex
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,landscape]{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
% pdfpages loads graphicx

\usepackage{pax}

\iffalse
  \usepackage{hyperref}
  \hypersetup{
    filebordercolor={1 1 0},
  }
\fi

\begin{document}
  \includepdf[pages=-]{links}
\end{document}
```

I gave it a shot using the online LaTex editor Overleaf [here](https://www.overleaf.com/read/hffvvvhvwqqd) and now we ended up with a clickable text inside of the circle, but not the outer one.

I hope this one would work for your specific `svg`.

Comment: Thanks Bilal, really appreciate your effort in the investigations! To be honest I don't understand how you created the SVG file (I presume you used an "HTML language"), anyway I can see the `links.pdf` in the overleaf project actually has two links ( I downloaded and opened it with `okular` on an `ubuntu 20.04` system). However, when I compile the project none of them is working in the generated pdf. Did you use any special compilation option? (I have a professional subscription in case it may be relevant...)

Comment: The `svg` format is viewable using any modern browser. Technically speaking, if you isolate the text part from `<svg>` ... `</svg>` and save it as a `.svg` file, then you got yourself your graphics file standing alone. I opened the file using `Chrome` then printed to a `pdf` (`Save as pdf` option). Since you are operating `Ubuntu`, I guess Firefox can print to `pdf` as well. I did not use any compilation options for that `pdf`.

Comment: It would be useful to share how do you generate your `LaTeX` document. What engine do you use? It makes most of the difference in your case. e.g. `Overleaf` was able to render one of the hyperlinks and yours was not able to compile any. Maybe if you'd share your `LaTeX` rendering engine, we can better investigate how to get it to behave better.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the clarifications :)) Regarding the engine, actually I was referring to the overleaf template you shared: when I enter that project I can see the `links.pdf` file and if I download it both links are working; however if I compile the project the links are not working in the output pdf (neither in the overleaf preview, nor if I download the document). More in general, my real use case involves (a slight modification of) this [template](https://www.overleaf.com/project/61018663d63e06252a36a3f9) and I am using `pdfLaTeX` as a compiler.

Comment: You did not download the `pdf` and examined the preview only, did you?

Comment: No, I checked both from the preview and from the downloaded file

Comment: This is a live example of how the rendering differs from one platform to another. Once I download the `pdf` I can click on the top link but not the bottom one. An idea occurred to me and it is painful, yet definitive, to apply. How about changing the existing `pdf` into a `LaTeX` then including it in the required `LaTex`? This would be really challenging but might actually work.

Comment: I was not aware this is possible, I gave it a try following [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8503/how-to-convert-pdf-to-latex) but didn't succeed for the moment. Unfortunately, the bounty is expiring so I have to make a decision on who to award it to...your help has been precious and I also learned a lot of things throughout, however `@rosa b.`'s short answer is the closest I can get to a solution (at least on my platform), despite not exactly what I hoped for. Thanks anyway @Bilal Quandeel, really appreciate your help! :D